# Можно ли повернуть спрайт на сколько-то градусов в Юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть блок,который в зависимости от окружения меняет спрайт. И в одном положении мне надо присвоить ему спрайт, но этот спрайт нужно повернуть на 90 градусов. Можно ли это сделать? У спрайтов нет никаких transform и тд. Просто нужно поместить повернутый спрайт. Нужно это без поворота самого объекта

Comment: для этого необходимо написать шейдер который имеет возможность поворота текстуры. Вероятнее всего если попробуешь освоить азы Shadergraph то это не доставит особой сложности.

Comment: Вдогонку к комментарию выше: можно обойтись и простыми, но топорными способами. Либо заготовить несколько спрайтов, изображение на котором уже будет повернуто нужным образом. Либо использовать разные префабы с нужными спрайтами (тогда этот объект нужно будет встроить в иерархию исходного объекта). Либо изображение разместить в дочернем/вложенном объекте и вращать под нужным углом уже этот дочерний объект.

Comment: А смысл если все эти перечисленные способо сложнее в реализации и более затратные по ресурсам? Если бы они хотя бы плюсы имели хоть какие на фоне предложенного.